# Jackson XML serilization do not wrap children and use child element names

Tags: jackson

I want to produce the following XML when serialising the class structure shown below:

```
<C>
  <D A="FrontRight"/>
  <W A="Green"/>
</C>
```

The Java code looks like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "C")
public static class Car {
    public Car(List children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List children;
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "D")
public static class Door {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A", isAttribute = true)
    public String placement = "FrontRight";
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "W")
public static class Window {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A", isAttribute = true)
    public String color = "Green";
}


    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List children;
}
```

And calling the mapper like:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Car(Arrays.asList(new Door(), new Window()))));
```

Produces this output:

```
<C>
  <children A="FrontRight"/>
  <children A="Green"/>
</C>
```

What should I do to get rid of `children` and have it use the named annotated on the classes placed in the list?

Comment: Use annotation `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "D")`  on field `public List children;`

Comment: That won't work since both child element then get the same element name:

    `<C>
      <D A="FrontRight"/>
      <D A="Green"/>
   </C>`